# iOS: Programmatically creating UIWindow results in wrong position

Tags: ios5, ios6, uiwindow, cgrect, uiscreen

In iOS 5.1.1, I have found that if I create my UIWindow (I'm tired of IB), and set its frame to [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds, the window shows up *under the status bar*. However if I do the same thing is iOS 6, it appears in the right spot just below the status bar.

```
CGRect r = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: r];
self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = self.detailViewController;
[self.window addSubview: detailViewController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

If however I insert r.origin.y += 20, to move the window below the status bar in iOS 5.1.1, this does not solve the problem and things only get weirder.

What is the proper way to place a UIWindow in iOS when creating it programmatically?
Thanks.

Comment: I am sure you will have much less problems if you go back to IB. I recently tried to fix layout issues with code and it took hours. I got it working but later tried doing the same with just IB, and a few clicks later it was working even better than my manual coding. I have learned it's best to use the tools are they are intended. Otherwise you hit edge cases which are hard to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` you'll want to use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]`. This will be the area of the screen below the status bar (if visible).

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to do this:

```
self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1;
```