# iOS - Interface Builder vs. Manual Programming

Tags: ios, xib

XCode offers a quite smart tool for creating layouts, outlets, actions etc. I worked with some Java Swing projects under Netbeans and all layouts stuff we were creating manually - that was a good way to having everything under control and being independent on any hard to maintain auto-generated stuff. And honestly I enjoyed that approach.

After reading such topics like that: 
[iOS: Programmatically creating UIWindow results in wrong position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12716725/ios-programmatically-creating-uiwindow-results-in-wrong-position) 
or
[do-you-prefer-building-your-interfaces-in-ib-or-programmatically-and-why](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35443/do-you-prefer-building-your-interfaces-in-ib-or-programmatically-and-why)

i can see that there is no sense in asking you "How it is with iOS" (no simple answer), but I think I can ask you *if (according to your experience) using IB has any limitations in that sense, that something it is more difficult or impossible to achieve using IB instead of create it manually?*

--
I new here so please let me know in case of my question is not suitable here...

Answer (score 2):

Well, one answer to you very general question might me: If your user interface is static, it is MUCH easier to define it in IB or storyboard. If is is dynamic (e.g. has moving items) you have to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience and asking a few people who worked with iOS, using interface builder does a lot of heavy lifting, some unnecessary boiler plate codes are removed for you.

This keeps your code base a lot smaller, without having you to write those generated code manually.

Personally if you are starting out, I recommend learning how to do it manually first and then learning IB after (if you don't mind the steep learning curve).

After you've understand how things are wired up, it empowers you to go further and make a more informed choice of when to use which technique.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm thinking of as well - it is probably better to know how does it exactly work and only then use something which can do it for you.